# Custom Metrics for Actuator Prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have activated the spring actuator prometheus endpont `/actuator/prometheus`. By adding the dependencies for micrometer and actuator and enabled prometheus endpont. How can i get there custom metrics?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need to register your metrics with the Micrometer Registry.

The following example creates the metrics in the constructor. The Micrometer Registry is injected as a constructor parameter:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    private final Counter myCounter;

    public MyComponent(MeterRegistry registry) {
        myCounter = Counter
                .builder("mycustomcounter")
                .description("this is my custom counter")
                .register(registry);
    }

    public String countedCall() {
        myCounter.increment();
    }
}
```

Once this is available, you'll have a metric *mycustomcounter_total* in the registry available in the */prometheus* URL. The suffix "total" is added to comply with the Prometheus naming conventions.

Comment: And note that `Counter` will be `io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter`. It seems that Prometheus Java Client for Spring Boot doesn't support Spring Boot 2 (at least by the time of writing): https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/issues/405#issuecomment-409817031